# Rails Condition Statement Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I have no idea why I am having problems with something so simple but this condition statement is just not working.

```
@battalion = Battalion.find(params[:id])
@soldier = @battalion.soldiers(:conditions => ["seniorleader = ?", "No"])
```

This shows the array of Soldiers but doesn't reflect the condition I have set.

I am sure I am doing something really simple wrong but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the syntax you have in line two, you're passing in **conditions** as a property of soldiers, and not actually paring down your list. You may try:

```
@soldier = @battalion.soldiers.find(:all, :conditions => ["seniorleader = ?", "No"])
```

The find method will help you to sort through your soldiers, i would also recommend you do some eager loading on your first line,

```
@battalion = Battalion.find(params[:id], :include => "soldiers")
```

So the @battalion object will already have all the soldiers information, and will not require a separate sql query for line two. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved it. I knew it was something stupid simple. Appreciate your time.

Comment: No, problem...been there done that. If you wanted to, you could do all of that in one line, check out this rails casts that has some more info http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins .